# How to send a post from twillio webhook using the body instead the params in the request?

Tags: http-post

There is a way to config the Twilio webhooks in the conversation product to send a post request to an endpoint and in the body send the information instead in the params?

Answer (score 0):

You would pass a payload of the JSON you want to send in your post body and then pass in a header called `x-www-form-urlencoded` which tells Twilio that you want the parameters to be sent in the body as form data. I'm not sure if it's limited to only a few parameters or not but I know that it works with `\"To\"` and `\"From\"` (as they need to be URL encoded). It would definitely work with `MessageSid`.

You could also use the `\"Bulk\"` post body format, which is just JSON. This would allow you to pass more parameters since it's just JSON. (You don't need to url encode them if you do this, so no need to have `x-www-form-urlencoded header`.)

```
        { 
            \"To\": \"+15551235555\", 
            \"From\": \"+15551234567\", 
            \"Body\": \"A text message\", 
            ...: ... 
        }
```

You should be able to send the information you want, along with the headers, from your endpoint and have it pass through Twilio.

Looks like this:

```
        curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages -d 'From=%2B15551234567&To=%2B15551235555&Body=Test' -u '{AccountSid}:{AuthToken}'
```

You can pass any JSON you want as a body using this option but make sure you've set your `\"Content-Type\"` header to `\"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\"`. This is pretty straightforward and makes it easy to pass in whatever parameters you want.

This isn't limited to text messages! This is exactly how I push data back into a Conversation or Action resource too so it'll work for things like card pushes too! You can use this to programmatically create a response that Twilio will process and then act on in your Conversation or Action instance.

And yeah … if you're going to support a webhook that takes form data then I would suggest adding some basic security checks since anyone could just post random stuff as form data if they wanted and get access to your endpoint. I'd recommend checking the Request Method as well to make sure it's POST.

If you're worried about someone passing in a bad value then you can just check the request body against some regex. I'd recommend checking the Twilio-To and Twilio-From params as well. You could also use the request header too, which is passed along with all webhooks:

```
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: xxx');
```